# Generated Excel File doesn't have adjusted row heights upon opening

Tags: opentbs, tinybutstrong

I've got a template with row height set to Auto.  When I merge it with cells that have multi-line data, the row heights are not adjusted when I open the merged document.  Oddly, the first few rows are not adjusted, but the ones further down in the sheet are.  If I open the non-adjusted cell to edit, even without making changes, the height is adjusted.

Do you know what's going on, and is there any way to avoid or workaround this?  Thanks.

Comment: How do you set the row height to Auto with Excel ?

Comment: We selected the row in the template.  On the Home ribbon we clicked the arrow under Format and chose AutoFit Row Height.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your bug: since the row is set to AutoFot row height + Wrap text, then all rows with line breaks are adjusted. Can you send a template + result example ?